# Pypy load and show picture

Tags: image, numpy, load, scipy, pypy

How do I load a picture (file) and save it into multidimensional numpy array and show it? I need example for pypy.

In python I have source code:

```
    from scipy import misc
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    picture = misc.imread('parrot.jpg')
    plt.imshow(newPicture)
    plt.show()
```